# how can i display message from user and admin?

Tags: php, html

Here is my mysql Database. This is the row for id, name, email, message, reply message

**id | name | email | message| reply_message**

Here is my code for admin message php

```
<b>Messages:</b><br/>
<?php
//Connect to your database....
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","u517914012_data");
$contact_array = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY email ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($contact_array))
{
echo"Email: ";
echo $row['email'];
echo"<br/>";
echo"Message: ";
echo $row['message'];
echo"<br/></br>";
}
?>
<br/><br/>
<b>Reply Users:</b>
<form name="form" id="form" action="user-panel.php" method="post">
Email:<input type="text" name="email" class="" maxlength="100" /><br/>
Message:<textarea name="reply_message" rows="5" cols="45" class=""></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my code for user message php

```
    <div id="formbox"> 
        <form name="form" id="form" action="message/submit.php" method="post">
            <ul id="ngothastyle3">
                <li>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="" maxlength="40" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="" maxlength="100" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" class=""></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>            </div>

<b>Admin Reply Info:<b><br/>

<table class="admin-table" border='1' style="position:relative; left:80px;font-size:13px;">
<tr>

<span style="position:relative; left:520px; font-size:20px; background :url('images/admin-header.png');">Creator Studio Admin Panel</span>
<hr width="104%">
<?php
$email=$login_session;
$req = mysql_query('SELECT email,reply_message FROM booking_members WHERE email ="$email ');

while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
{
?>
    <tr>    
        <td class="left" >
        &nbsp<?php echo htmlentities($dnn['reply_message'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>&nbsp
        </td>               
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Can somebody help me please. The problem is in the user message php.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What is 'The problem'? What is not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You are using `mysql_query` in the second file while you are using `mysqli_*` in the first. Also, I don't see a connect to your mysql database in the second file.

Comment: how can i display the data from the database when user php page submit the forms. and display the data to admin php page vice versa

Comment: i have a config.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
$req = mysql_query('SELECT email,reply_message FROM booking_members WHERE email ="$email ');
```

replace it with

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT email,reply_message FROM booking_members WHERE email ='$email'  ");
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\sample1\user-panel.php on line 140

Comment: use mysqli or mysql  you are using both in your code please check it and update,always work with one of them

Comment: then for admin$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","u517914012_data");
$contact_array = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY email ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($contact_array))